# Beautiful Soup doesn't read multiple root tags

Tags: xml, beautifulsoup

I have a markup file that looks like:

```
<d id="0001" type="story"><P>xxx</P></d>
<d id="0002" type="story"><P>yyy</P></d>
```

and I'm using the 'xml' parser of Beautiful Soup.

When I ask for pretty print, it will only print the first , but not the second. Also when I call `soup.find_all("d")`, the list will only contain one `<d></d>`. I wonder how I could get to the second d, i.e. the one with id 0002.

Result of pretty print:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d id="0001" type="story">
 <P>
  xxx
 </P>
</d>
```

When I add another layer around it, the parser will get both d's:

```
<c>
<d id="0001" type="story"><P>xxx</P></d>
<d id="0002" type="story"><P>yyy</P></d>
</c>
```

I just don't understand why it won't allow a flat structure of 2 or more parallel d's.

Comment: Because ... this is an XML parser, and the document you are passing to it is not a valid XML document... See https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#NT-document: "[Definition: There is exactly one element, called the root, or document element, no part of which appears in the content of any other element.]" Any chance you can add a dummy tag at the beginning/end (e.g. prepend <foo> and append </foo>) - which will make it valid?

Comment: "I just don't understand why it won't allow a flat structure of 2 or more parallel d's. ". As @user8734617 states: An XML parser does allow 2 or more parallel `d`s, but not at the root level which requires **exactly one** element called the root element.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That makes sense! I already added a dummy tag so it now works. I'm just curious why it won't allow a flat structure. I guess the corpus I'm reading in just has that flat format, and I need to add the dummy tag for every one of them. In fact, in the documentation of the corpus, they said 'markup', not 'xml', so it's my bad...